# php7.4-imap Installed on Ubuntu 16.04 But imap_open() is not working and also says php7.4-imap doesn't exists

Tags: 16.04, server, email, thunderbird, postfix

We have PHP 7.4 installed and want to integrate IMAP to receive emails. Also installed php7.4-IMAP but still imap_open() not responding. When trying to enable IMAP showing an error like the module does not exist.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccfpc.png)

Comment: Most likely not a fix to the issue but just a reminder 16.04 is EOL in April and there will be no more support or upgrades to it. Time to think about an upgrade.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of PHP installed, don’t forget to specify that you want to use 7.4 rather than the other version.

Comment: @Matigo yes I have mentioned the same PHP version which I want to use. But still the same.

Comment: @David thank you so much for the information. I will update the Ubuntu version asap.